# sizeof with function template argument in declaration doesn't match the definition

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, sizeof

The following program

```
template<int> 
struct R{};

struct S
{
    template<typename T>
    auto f(T t) -> R<sizeof(t)>;
};

template<typename T>
auto S::f(T t) -> R<sizeof(t)> {}
```

compiles with Clang, but GCC 10.2 gives an error for the definition of `f`

> error: no declaration matches 'R<sizeof (t)> S::f(T)'

This looks like a GCC bug, especially since GCC trunk currently gives an ICE

> internal compiler error: canonical types differ for identical types 'R<sizeof (t)>' and 'R<sizeof (t)>'

Also, GCC compiles the program when the return type in both the declaration and the definition is changed to `R<sizeof (T)>`.

Is the program valid?

Here's the [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ezj4bW9xn).

Comment: Well that's an interesting one. `t` _should be_ within the name scope to be used in that `sizeof` expression. What's most interesting to me is that this fails even if you do something silly like `R<sizeof(decltype(t))>` (which I tried since gcc _does_ handle `decltype(t)` correctly). I'm pretty sure this is a GCC bug.

Comment: @Human-Compiler Yeah, it seems to have something to do with how gcc generates the "canonical" types when `sizeof` is involved. I'm definitely leaning towards it being a gcc bug.

Comment: Looks fixed in GCC trunk: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8vaMPG3eW