# Is a leading return type method declaration, using decltype, compatible with a trailing return type definition?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, decltype, trailing-return-type

When using [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype),
is it permissible to use the traditional leading return type syntax in a
declaration:

```
  decltype(expr) foo();
```

and then use
[C++11 trailing return type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trailing_return_type)
syntax in the definition?

```
  auto foo() -> decltype(expr) { /*...*/ }
```

I think the answer is yes, as C++11 8.3.5p1 (leading return type) and
8.3.5p2 (trailing return type) both seem to yield the same final type
description regardless of which side the return type appears on, and
7.1.6.2p4 (`decltype`) doesn't seem to have anything that would
change that.  Furthermore, the note in 9.3p9 shows an example of
declaring a member using a typedef, but explains it could not be defined
with a typedef, implying that they do not have to use exactly the same
syntactic conventions.

However, I've got an example where both Clang and GCC do not think it is
allowed, although MSVC does
([godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/aP1MjceW8)):

```
// The class must be a template for the problem to happen.
template <typename T>
struct Class {
  // This has to be inside the class for the problem to happen.
  int dataMember;

  // All is fine if I use trailing return type here.
  //auto method() -> decltype(dataMember);

  // But it fails with leading return type in the declaration.
  decltype(dataMember) method();
};

// Definition uses trailing return type.
template <typename T>
auto Class<T>::method() -> decltype(dataMember) {
  return 3;
}
```

Clang 16.0.0 says:

```
<source>:16:16: error: return type of out-of-line definition of 'Class::method' differs from that in the declaration
auto Class<T>::method() -> decltype(dataMember) {
               ^
<source>:11:24: note: previous declaration is here
  decltype(dataMember) method();
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

GCC 13.1 says, somewhat more informatively but dubiously:

```
<source>:16:6: error: no declaration matches 'decltype (((Class<T>*)this)->Class<T>::dataMember) Class<T>::method()'
   16 | auto Class<T>::method() -> decltype(dataMember) {
      |      ^~~~~~~~
<source>:11:24: note: candidate is: 'decltype (Class<T>::dataMember) Class<T>::method()'
   11 |   decltype(dataMember) method();
      |                        ^~~~~~
<source>:3:8: note: 'struct Class<T>' defined here
    3 | struct Class {
      |        ^~~~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

MSVC 19 is happy with this code, even if I add code that instantiates
`Class` and calls `method` (although it then issues a warning about
electing to inline the method, which is a little weird).

I'm inclined to believe that these two signatures (one with leading
return type and one with trailing return type) are in fact supposed to
be equivalent in C++, and that furthermore I am allowed to use leading
return type in the declaration and trailing return type in the
definition, despite these two compilers' objections, because for both of
them, the problem only happens if the class is a template and
`dataMember` is declared inside it (suggesting the compilers might both
have similar bugs).

Have I overlooked some provision that makes this not permissible?

(Tangent: Why would I *want* the declaration and definition to differ in
this regard?  Normally I would not, but this is the output of a code
transformation tool.  The declaration is in the original code, which
usually uses leading return type, and which I want to only minimally
change, while the definition is generated, and the trailing return type
syntax is very convenient in that context due to all class members being
in scope there.)

Clarification: In the example above, `dataMember` has type `int` (because I wanted it to be minimal).  But this evidently causes the answer to depend on [CWG2064](https://wg21.link/CWG2064) because it is not a dependent type.  My intended focus is the general case, including dependent types.  So, the ideal answer would instead primarily answer for the case where `int` has been replaced with `T` ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/76fvh6eqc)), with the degenerate case of `int` treated separately (if necessary).

Comment: The problem is not where you think. [example 1](https://godbolt.org/z/qqsqMvTj6).  [example 2](https://godbolt.org/z/Ta58YsYxa). [example 3](https://godbolt.org/z/46fxYx7qo).

Comment: @n.m. Those examples show that the problem disappears if (1) we remove `template`, (2) the member is `static`, or (3) we remove `decltype` from the declaration.  (1) is already stated, (2) is not surprising given GCC's error message mentioning `this`, and (3) is also not surprising since the `decltype` is evaluated separately from the signatures in question.  So I'm not sure what you mean by "not where you think".

Comment: iirc this is not a bug but intended, though difficult to find the duplicate, I have no idea what to search for

Comment: The problem is most definitely not in two different return type styles being incompatible when `decltype` is used. [example 4](https://godbolt.org/z/96vGMe8r4) [example 5](https://godbolt.org/z/nPY5zKdqf).

Comment: @n. m. Hmmm.  Those two show that GCC (but not Clang) has issues with `decltype` even when consistently using leading return type, which is interesting.  But there could be more than one compiler bug involved, and in any case, my primary question is about the language rather than the compilers.

Comment: Thinking of it some more, I am now almost convinced that this is underspecified by the standard.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67039498/sizeof-with-function-template-argument-in-declaration-doesnt-match-the-definiti      kinda related

Comment: "When using decltype, is it permissible to use the traditional leading return type syntax in a declaration" - Why don't you just *try* and than the compiler will tell you if it's ok.

Answer (score 6):

Neither gcc nor clang implement [CWG2064](https://wg21.link/CWG2064).

This means since `dataMember` "involves a template parameter" (what clang calls "instantiation-dependent") by virtue of being a member of the current-instantiation, `decltype(dataMember)` is a "unique dependent type".

[[temp.type]p4](https://wg21.link/temp.type#4) (without wording changed by DR2064):

> If an expression *e* involves a template parameter, `decltype(`*e*`)` denotes a unique dependent type. Two such *decltype-specifiers* refer to the same type only if their *expressions* are equivalent ([temp.over.link]).

[[temp.over.link]p5](https://wg21.link/temp.over.link#5):

> Two expressions involving template parameters are considered *equivalent* if two function definitions containing the expressions would satisfy the one-definition rule, [...]

[[class.mfct.non.static]p2](https://wg21.link/class.mfct.non.static#2):

> When an *id-expression* ([expr.prim.id]) that is neither part of a class member access syntax ([expr.ref]) nor the unparenthesized operand of the unary `&` operator ([expr.unary.op]) is used where the current class is X ([expr.prim.this]), if name lookup ([basic.lookup]) resolves the name in the *id-expression* to a non-static non-type member of some class `C`, and if either the *id-expression* is potentially evaluated or `C` is `X` or a base class of `X`, the *id-expression* is transformed into a class member access expression ([expr.ref]) using `(*this)` as the *postfix-expression* to the left of the `.` operator.

So at your declaration `decltype(dataMember) method();`, `dataMember` refers to the same thing as `Class::dataMember` because there is no `this` (therefore there is no current class), but at your definition `template <typename T> auto Class<T>::method() -> decltype(dataMember)`, `dataMember` is `(*this).dataMember`.
Even though they have the same tokens, these expressions are not equivalent because of the ODR [[basic.def.odr]p(14.5)](https://wg21.link/basic.def.odr#14.5):

> In each such definition, corresponding names, looked up according to [basic.lookup], shall refer to the same entity, [...]

(`(*this).dataMember` is not the same entity as `Class<T>::dataMember`)

You can see this is the case if you make sure there is no `(*this).` transformation:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Class {
  int dataMember;

  decltype(std::type_identity_t<Class<T>>::dataMember) method();
};

template <typename T>
auto Class<T>::method() -> decltype(std::type_identity_t<Class<T>>::dataMember) {
  return 3;
}
```

---

If gcc and clang were to implement CWG2064, `decltype(dataMember)` would no longer be a dependent type and would simply be `int`, so this would work.

You would run into the same issue if you were to make the type of `dataMember` dependent:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Class {
  T dataMember;

  decltype(dataMember) method();
};

template <typename T>
auto Class<T>::method() -> decltype(dataMember) {
  return 3;
} // Error: return type is different
```

Comment: Nice analysis!  Let me confirm my understanding: (1) in the leading return case, `this` is not in scope, whereas it is for the trailing return, and consequently `decltype(dataMember)` in the two locations is not equivalent; and (2) therefore one cannot, in general, create a compatible definition by moving a leading `decltype` return type to the trailing position (even if CWG2064 is implemented, as shown in your final example).

Comment: And (3) the answer to the question in the title is **no** if the `decltype` expression is type-dependent (per CWG2064), but otherwise **yes**.  That is, there's nothing in the language that directly or intentionally prohibits associating leading and trailing returns, but the rules for `decltype` sometimes indirectly have that effect.

Comment: Hmm, it seems the standard might have a defect, because the "current class" is defined even in a leading return type ([expr.prim.this]/2) but the transformation is ill-formed there, because you can't use `this` at that point.

Comment: But also, "This transformation does not apply in the template definition context", so it seems that Clang and GCC are non-conforming in a second way.

Comment: @BrianBi Yeah "current class" seemed way too broad. It even applies inside static member functions, but `struct X { int x; static int f() { return sizeof(x); } };` should obviously not transform. And yes, this transformation shouldn't be done in the template definition context, so it looks like clang/gcc are wrong here

Comment: @ScottMcPeak The left return type is in a slightly different context than the trailing return. The only visible difference seems to be whether `this` is available, and as Brian Bi pointed out, that shouldn't make a difference ( https://wg21.link/class.mfct.non.static#2.sentence-3 ) (and also the function arguments: https://godbolt.org/z/YhMPdxGrE but you probably meant when lookup finds the same declarations). Otherwise, return types should be an unevaluated context so the presence of `this` shouldn't matter

Comment: _`(*this).dataMember` is not the same entity as `Class<T>::dataMember`_ Huh? They both denote the same NSDM

Comment: @LanguageLawyer https://wg21.link/basic.pre#3 `(*this).dataMember` is denotes an object, `Class<T>::dataMember` does not (it's a class member)

Comment: The definition of «entity» is defective, it shall not include objects. Lookup can not result in object. ODR talks about lookup. `dataMember` in `(*this).dataMember` is a member-qualified name, and its lookup context is the type of its object expression (http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.qual.general#2.sentence-3). And qualified names undergo qualified name lookup in their lookup contexts http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.qual.general#3.sentence-2. Unless you believe the type of `*this` is not `Class<T>`, the lookup contexts are the same. This can't result in diff entities for the same name

Comment: @Artyer I have posted my understanding of your answer as another answer.  I'd appreciate your feedback on whether that's accurate.

Comment: _(`(*this).dataMember` is not the same entity as `Class<T>::dataMember`)
You can see this is the case if you make sure there is no `(*this).` transformation_ [Looks like `std::type_identity_t<Class<T>>::dataMember` and `type_identity_t<Class<T>>::dataMember` (with my own `type_identity_t`) are also different entities ](https://godbolt.org/z/5bGqhW9rq)

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by Artyer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76854721/2659307)
appears consistent with how Clang and GCC
have implemented things.  As there is still discussion
about whether it's the correct interpretation of the language standard,
I'm holding off on accepting it for the moment.

But I want to state my understanding of that answer and invite
correction:

1. Normally, leading return type and trailing return type declarations
   *are* compatible.  Nothing in the standard directly or intentionally
   prohibits using one for a declaration and the other for a
   definition.
2. However, when `decltype` is used in a template context, an
   incompatibility can arise due to subtleties of `decltype` semantics.
   Specifically:

   - In the leading return position, `this` is not in scope, so
     `decltype(dataMember)` means
     `decltype(Class<T>::dataMember)`.  (I have my doubts about this
     because [[expr.prim.this]p2](https://wg21.link/expr.prim.this#2)
     talks about the "innermost class scope" and we are still inside a
     class scope, right?)
   - In the trailing return position, `this` *is* in scope, so
     `decltype(dataMember)` "is transformed into"
     `decltype(this->dataMember)`, per
     [[class.mfct.non.static]p2](https://wg21.link/class.mfct.non.static#2).
   - These are not equivalent because `Class<T>::dataMember` refers to a member
     declaration (a compile-time notion) while `this->dataMember` refers to an
     object (a run-time notion).  (This claim is a point of contention.
     But the GCC error message seems to focus on this
     difference.)
   - For the example in my question, the behavior depends on the
     language change [CWG2064](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2064.html)
     because the type of `dataMember` is manifestly `int`, potentially
     obviating the above points.
   - If `dataMember` had been declared as type `T`, then the
     incompatibility would persist even after CWG2064.  (In
     retrospect, I wish I had done that because the concrete
     `int` type allows the core issue I care about to be
     bypassed.)
3. Consequently, one cannot, in general, move a return type specified
   using `decltype` from the leading to trailing return positions and
   maintain compatibility between declaration and definition.  Hence the
   answer to the question asked in the title, "Is a leading return type
   method declaration, using decltype, compatible with a trailing return
   type definition?", is **not in general**.

Comment: I recognize it's a little weird to post this as an answer.  I do not intend to ultimately accept my own answer.  But this is much too long for a comment, I didn't want to pollute the question with content that only pertains to one answer, and editing this much clarification and restatement into that answer would be presumptuous.  So proposing a new answer seemed like the least bad option.

Comment: _These are not equivalent because `Class<T>::dataMember` refers to a member declaration (a compile-time notion) while `this->dataMember` refers to an object_ [What about `std::type_identity_t<Class<T>>::dataMember` and `type_identity_t<Class<T>>::dataMember` (with my own `type_identity_t`)? Do they refer to different things? Which ones?](https://godbolt.org/z/5bGqhW9rq)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer This seems like a good point; I would expect them to refer to the same thing.  And at the moment (even before your latest comment) I suspect you are right that the claim in bullet point 3 ("These are not equivalent ...") is incorrect w.r.t. the language standard (but I still have a high degree of uncertainty).  I'd welcome another answer to study if you're inclined to provide one.  :)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer In your case, the compiler is right to say that your `type_identity_t` isn't equivalent to `std::type_identity_t`, because it's legal to specialize your own `struct type_identity` later in the translation unit to have the 2 type_identity_t behave differently (as long as you don't break ODR): [example (godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/z/GY3zP95Wb).

Comment: @VincentSaulue-Laborde https://godbolt.org/z/zT4Woo6vx

Comment: @LanguageLawyer My point is that the compiler didn't "simplify" the expression `::type_identity<T>::type` into `T` first and foremost because it's not even correct in general. But I'm also quite doubtful that a C++ compliant compiler is even allowed to transform such expressions for the sake of declaration&definition matching (I'm no ISO C++ expert). The expression `::type_identity<T>::type` isn't equivalent to `T`. `std::type_identity<T>::type` isn't equivalent to `T` either: no preferential treatment required by the standard. Your 2 `decltype` expressions aren't equivalent expressions.